# My docker backend enabled with mongo and node fails after sometime showing error of javascript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

**Docker file
**FROM node:16

## WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "./"]

## Install some depenendencies

## COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

## Default command

CMD ["npm", "start"]

**docker-compose .yml
**
version: "3.8"
services:
web:
build: .
environment:
- mongoConnectionString=mongodb://mongo:27017/temp
ports:
- "8001:8001"
depends_on:
- mongo
mongo:
image: mongo
ports:
- "27019:27017

<--- JS stacktrace --->
web_1    |
web_1    | FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
web_1    |  1: 0xb08e80 node::Abort() [node]

After some time when my backend runs it fails with this error